# Render command button based on boolean if condition

Tags: apex, visualforce, html

I want my command button to be visible if a boolean variable "ReviewedByHCP" is set to false, and hidden if it's set to true.

Here's what I have:

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:commandbutton id="MarkReviewBtn" rendered="{!IF(testResultObj.ReviewedByHCP == false), true,false}" styleClass="btn btnGreen" value="{!$Label.JC_CM_Mark_as_Reviewed}" 
           onclick="markAsReviewed()" action="{!markAsReviewed}"/>
</apex:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, I knew it was something simple:

```
<apex:form>
  <apex:commandbutton id="MarkReviewBtn" rendered="{!!testResultObj.ReviewedByHCP}" styleClass="btn btnGreen" value="{!$Label.JC_CM_Mark_as_Reviewed}" 
 onclick="markAsReviewed()" action="{!markAsReviewed}"/>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: It is way less confusing if you use `NOT(condition)` instead of `!condition` in a merge field so you don't get two `!` characters in a row.

Comment: @AdrianLarson ...or some whitespace `{! !testResultObj.ReviewedByHCP }`

Answer (score 4):

The reason your logic failed was that your close paren is in the wrong spot in your merge syntax. Correct `IF` syntax is `IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)`.

Incorrect:

```
rendered="{!IF(testResultObj.ReviewedByHCP == false), true,false}"
```

Correct:

```
rendered="{!IF(testResultObj.ReviewedByHCP, false, true)}"
```

However, even the correct syntax is excessively verbose. It demonstrates a common anti-pattern in merge syntax, namely:

> Any condition written `IF(condition, true, false)` can be rewritten as `condition`.

The corollary here is that:

> Any condition written `IF(condition, false, true)` can be rewritten as `NOT(condition)`

So in summary, as you noted, negation is much simpler.

```
rendered="{!NOT(testResultObj.ReviewedByHCP)}"
```